# How Many types of Http Handlers are there in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, handler

I just want to know exactly how many types of Http Handlers are available in ASP.NET ?

Comment: Please clarify what "Handler" you mean? Classes deriving from `IHttpHandler`?

Comment: yes.. How many Types of HTTP Handlers available in asp.net ?

Comment: Brief information about Handler and how to create your own Http handler is given here http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19389/HTTP-Handlers-and-HTTP-Modules-in-ASPNET.htm

Answer (score 3):

The **[`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Background)** article states that there are Four Http Handlers. You can even create your own custom Http Handlers (which is mentioned in the same article)

```
1) ASP.NET page handler (*.aspx)
2) Web service handler (*.asmx)
3) Generic Web handler (*.ashx)
4) Trace handler (trace.axd)
```

In other way of understanding, there are two types of Http handlers

```
1) Asynchronous
2) Synchronous
//mentioned in the same article
```

Comment: And MVC got it's own handler.